# How to convert TEXT to number

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

I have one column with date format as below
But I would like to convert it to this format 2020/08/15.
"Datevalue" is not working in my excel(O365, I already reinstalled the office and asked the expert)

Is there someone can help on this? thank you.

Aug 15, 2020
Aug 16, 2020
Aug 18, 2020

Answer (score 0):

Select the cells or the columns you want to format.

Then go to "Home" > "Number" > "Costum"

Under "costum" enter YYYY/MM/DD in the "Type" field and press "OK"

Comment: Hello, there is a error pop up, "excel can't not use this format  JJJJ/MM/TT.

Comment: Sorry, my excel is in a different language for english the format is: yyyy/mm/dd

Answer (score 0):

To convert a text date in a cell to a serial number, use the DATEVALUE function. Then copy the formula, select the cells that contain the text dates, and use Paste Special to apply a date format to them.

Follow these steps:

1.Select a blank cell and verify that its number format is General.

2.In the blank cell:

a.Enter =DATEVALUE(

b.Click the cell that contains the text-
formatted date that you want to convert.

c.Enter )

d.Press ENTER, and the DATEVALUE function
returns the serial number of the date
that is represented by the text date.

3.After you drag the fill handle, you should have a range of cells with serial numbers that corresponds to the range of cells that contain text dates.

4.Select the cell or range of cells that contains the serial numbers, and then on the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click Copy.

Keyboard shortcut:  You can also press
CTRL+C.

5.Select the cell or range of cells that contains the text dates, and then on the Home tab, in the Clipboard group, click the arrow below Paste, and then click Paste Special.

6.In the Paste Special dialog box, under Paste, select Values, and then click OK.

7.On the Home tab, click the popup window launcher next to Number.

8.In the Category box, click Date, and then click the date format that you want in the Type list.

9To delete the serial numbers after all of the dates are converted successfully, select the cells that contain them, and then press DELETE.

Answer (score 0):

Convert "Aug" to number "8" first：

```
=MONTH(1&LEFT(A1,3))
```

[image]

Then extract the date and year：

Date:

```
=MID(A1,4,3)
```

Year:

```
=RIGHT(A1,4)
```

[image]

Then merge the three cells:

```
=F1&"/"&D1&"/"&E1
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, as I said Date value is not work in my excel, don't know why? I already re-install the O365 and contact the expert, but it just can work.